# haskell foldl with (++)

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was playing with Haskell and ghci when I found this which really bothers me:

```
foldl (++) [[3,4,5], [2,3,4], [2,1,1]] []
```

I expected to get this: `[3,4,5,2,3,4,2,1,1]`
However it gets:

```
[[3,4,5],[2,3,4],[2,1,1]]
```

As far as I understand foldl, it should be this:

```
(([] ++ [3, 4, 5]) ++ [2, 3, 4]) ++ [2, 1, 1]
```

If I type this in ghci it really is `[3,4,5,2,3,4,2,1,1]`.

And the other strange thing is this:

```
Prelude> foldl1 (++) [[3,4,5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 1]]
[3,4,5,2,3,4,2,1,1]
```

I expect foldl and foldl1 to behave in the same way. So what does foldl actually do?

Comment: Note that [the source for concat](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#concat) is simply `concat = foldr (++) []`

Comment: I was trying to make my own concat. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The order of arguments is wrong. The right one is:
`foldl (++) [] [[3,4,5], [2,3,4], [2,1,1]]`
(That is, first the accumulator, then the list.)

Comment: Getting the argument order wrong is not silly. Happens all the time, especially with a concept like folding, where every language expects the arguments in another order. Not asking the question or simply giving up without even trying, that would be silly.

Comment: It does make sense, though. It is more likely that you would want to use the same accumulator for different lists, than use the same list with different accumulators. Likewise, it is more likely that you want to reuse the same function with different accumulators. Therefore, the order `f a l` makes sense. Scala OTOH has syntactic sugar for a function as the very last argument, therefore it makes sense to have the function last. So, while every language has a different order, the order is not arbitrary. You can actually deduce it by thinking about the characteristics of the language.

Comment: I never got why foldl and foldr had different signatures.

Answer (score 5):

You switched the arguments around. `foldl` takes the accumulator's starting value first, then the list to fold. So what happens in your case is that `foldl` folds over the empty list and thus returns the starting value, which is `[[3,4,5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 1]]`. This will do what you want:

```
foldl (++) [] [[3,4,5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You got the argument order wrong

```
Prelude> :t foldl
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
Prelude> :t foldl1
foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

The initial value comes first. In your case, your initial value was `[[3,4,5],[2,3,4],[2,1,1]]` and you folded over the empty list, so you got back the initial value.